# Determine if input field is in edit mode

Tags: javascript, input, field, state

I have a form where if the user presses ESC it is closed. Anytime a field is changed I run code to save the value based on onchange events. So typically all fields have been committed before the ESC key has been hit.

However, if the user clicks in the field and changes the value but doesn't tab or hit enter the onchange doesn't fire. So then the change is not committed.

And while the field is in the edit state the following code doesn't run when the ESC key is pressed.

Is there a way to change the functionality of the ESC key while a field is still in the edit mode?

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
       // this assumes all of the fields have been committed.
       $('#dialog-form').dialog('destroy').html('');
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is missing a right parenthesis at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the behaviour of ESC while editing the form, consider that if you listen to the document, you can detect keypresses from anywhere. If you listen to only your form, you will only detect keypresses from within that form.

```
<form id="foo">
<input type="text" />
</form>

<script>

$("#foo").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        // This code will run if you press escape while editing the form.
    }
})

$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        // This code will run if you press escape from anywhere.
    }
})

</script>
```

For your other problem, I don't think elements have a `.dialog()` method.